# API result not deserializing as expected

Tags: c#, api, blazor-server-side, .net-5, asp.net5

I am building a blazor web app that is talking to a .NET 5 API.

I am getting deserialization errors and i believe the reason is because the object being returned is not exactly like the object I have defined.

class is as follows:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid WorkspaceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
}
```

API:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllLocations()
        {
            return Ok(_locationManagementRepository.GetAllLoacations());
        }
```

Data Access method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Location>> GetAllLoacations()
        {
            var locations = new [] {
                new Location{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Location 1", WorkspaceID = Guid.NewGuid(),Floors = null, ImagePath = null},
                new Location{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Location 2", WorkspaceID = Guid.NewGuid(),Floors = null, ImagePath = null},
                new Location{Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Location 3", WorkspaceID = Guid.NewGuid(),Floors = null, ImagePath = null}
            };
            return await Task.FromResult(locations);
        }
```

Blazor service that queries API:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Location>> GetAllLocations()
        {
            _httpClient.SetBearerToken(await _tokenManager.RetrieveAccessTokenAsync());

            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Location>>
                (await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/location"),
                new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
        }
```

the JSON returned to this methos is as follows:

```
{"result":[{"id":"e029e1cb-3ea2-4b2c-acae-5e693d2ece46","workspaceID":"985f2695-f36e-4481-9b7c-b1e00bbb4ac3","name":"Location 1","imagePath":null,"floors":null},{"id":"c4ccb92b-9cc8-4e08-bba3-22f61c1fe7e5","workspaceID":"67d05f55-5bd4-4e8f-93b3-b3daa9155535","name":"Location 2","imagePath":null,"floors":null},{"id":"a42073da-239d-428e-a318-d3dc7cfd221b","workspaceID":"d3a14500-ddcd-486f-a96e-5c86373c092d","name":"Location 3","imagePath":null,"floors":null}],"id":2,"exception":null,"status":5,"isCanceled":false,"isCompleted":true,"isCompletedSuccessfully":true,"creationOptions":0,"asyncState":null,"isFaulted":false}
```

The error I get is:

> JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List

My question is, what is the correct way to go about handing this to deserialize the data so I can pass it onto my blazor component? Do I need to create a view model that has a single result property defined as a List or am I missing something in my API/Blazor application that will make this just work! :-)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have some class with a `ICollection<Location> Result`  property or similar?

Comment: That api response contains several instances of what look like `Location`s. Does your component accept a collection of them? Are you looping over the data and creating a component for each one? We can't fix code we can't see, what is your code and what result do you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the really poor info, I have updated with what I hope is more useful information for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get to the bottom of it, the problem was at the API Level, I was returning an IAction result instead of a Task once I changed the method return type everything started working!

Old:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllLocations()
        {
            return Ok(_locationManagementRepository.GetAllLoacations());
        }
```

New:

```
[HttpGet]
        public Task<IActionResult> GetAllLocations()
        {
            return Ok(_locationManagementRepository.GetAllLoacations());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JSON expert, so forgive me if "result" is s standard leader for a JSON API response, but my guess would be that it's trying to unpack the "result" object as the array.

I might try something like:

```
public class result {
   List<Location> locations{get; set;}
}
```

then unpacking

```
(await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<result>).locations
```